# My AJAX API plugin isn't working

Tags: plugins, ajax

I've created a tiny AJAX plugin to count hits on my articles and bypass caching but it just isn't working and not throwing up any errors.

Can you see what I am doing wrong here?

```
<?php
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_LogHit_callback', 'LogHit_callback');
add_action('wp_ajax_LogHit_callback', 'LogHit_callback');

function HitCount() {
  ?>
  <script type="text/javascript" >
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var data = {
        action: 'LogHit_callback',
        PostId:'<?php echo get_the_ID() ?>'
    };
    jQuery.post('http://www.test.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php', data, function( r ) {
alert( r );
  });
 </script>
 <?php


  function LogHit_callback() {
    global $wpdb; // this is how you get access to the database

    $postId = $_POST['PostId'];
    $hits = get_post_meta((int)$postId, 'hit-counter', true);
    $hits = $hits + 1;
    update_post_meta((int)$postId, 'hit-counter', (int)$hits);
    return $postId;
    exit; // this is required to return a proper result
  }
 }
```

It writes the following into my HTML where I call the HitCount function

```
 <script type="text/javascript" >

 jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
   var data = {
    action: 'LogHit_callback',
    PostId:'86505'
};
jQuery.ajax('http://www.lazygamer.net/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php', data, function( r )      {
     alert( r );
  });

 </script>
```

I know hard coding the URL to admin-ajax is bad but I am trying to rule out issues.
if I put an alert inside the ajax call that is written to the html it works so I know that is being called.

But the second alert in the plugin file never gets called?

Comment: closing `}` missing after `alert( r );`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no PHP function `alert`, that's why your function throws an error and doesn't proceed with the rest of your code. You have to return something from the `LogHit_callback` function using `return` (or echo it with `echo`) and then alert it with JavaScript, that is add following code to your `post` function:

```
jQuery.post( 'http://www.test.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php', data, function( r ) {
    alert( r );
});
```

I believe that this is the correct syntax for `post()`. Remember that you can always debug AJAX requests with browser's developer tools. You will then know exactly what's going on.

Comment: I can't find the ajax request using Chromes developer tools.. what should I be looking for? I changed the alert/return issue and updated the main post but still nothing

Comment: Just saw an error now "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ) " after my return

Comment: There should be a comma after <code>data</code> and before <code>function</code> in your JavaScript. Check my example. Just copy the code from my example, you have syntax errors all over the place.

Comment: Sorry bad editing on my side, the comma existed in the actual code

Comment: But then you haven't included the closing bracket after `alert( r );`, that's why you have a syntax error.

Comment: Okay now that my syntax is correct I can see the post to admin-ajax.php and this is the response <b>Warning</b>:  call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'LogHit_callback' not found or invalid function name in <b>/usr/www/users/rfdsff/wp-includes/plugin.php</b> on line <b>406</b><br />

Comment: more bad syntax.. thanks for the help it's working now :)